# Spring MVC 3 - Date input is autocorrecting

Tags: spring-mvc

After searching for a while I'm asking for help.

On a Spring MVC 3 project I'm a little in trouble about date "auto correction":
Let's explain that:
    - I've got a view with  a masked Input (dd/MM/yyyy) to fill a Date property in my model.
    - My file is bound with an simpleDateFormatter (defined in @InitBinder)

Everything works fine until I input a wrong date (i.e. 32/08/2012). If my view is submitted with such a wrong data, Spring corrects it to 01/09/2012 and so my field is not rejecting the value which is messing me up.

I can't give my code cause I'm not allowed to.

If I'm not really clear just say it and I'll try to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Sorry for this useless topic: In InitBinder where the dateformatters are described and binded to fields. If I had setLenenient(true) to each SimpleDateFormatter my problem is sovled